# reloading a tableview when source is NSURLConnection and gets new data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I tabController app with uitableview getting NSURLconnection data and trying to display it. I can't figure out the issue. If I replace the connection with an array I'm storing all the drill-down works, but updating doesn't, So I think that the tableView end of things is fine. BUT:

If I put [[self.tableview] reloadData]; in the -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:

This causes a loop of my parent row on the view. When you select a row it repopulates with the same row "Title", not the child of it. If I remove the [[self.tableview] reloadData]; The tableDataSource3 is empty and does not get refreshed with URL data so I need it.I have NSLogs that are showing the update so I know it's getting updated.

If I put [[self.tableview] reloadData]; in the ViewDidAppear:

the View is empty until I move out of the table and back (the app is a tabcontroller with tableViews). If I add a row in the database and update via NSURL connection the tableView stays as it is, but if I select a row the new data that was updated appears in the pushed table.

If I put [[self.tableview] reloadData]; in the ViewWillAppear:

the View is empty until I move out of the table and back. however, the pushed child view is empty.

Any Ideas?

Here is the end of the NSURLconnection meth

```
    -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn3 {

 ~ JSON STUFF~

  NSArray *test = [json objectForKey:@"Rows"];
  tableDataSource3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:test];


  [json release];
  [conn3 release];
  self.receivedData =nil;
  [[self tableview] reloadData];
    }
```

Here is the selection method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  //Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 //Get the children of the present item.
 NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

 if([Children count] == 0) {

  ItemDetailViewController *dvController = [[ItemDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
  [dvController release];
 }
 else {

   //Prepare to tableview.
  ThirdTab *rvController = [[ThirdTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


  rvController.CurrentLevel3 += 1;


  rvController.CurrentTitle3 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

  rvController.tableDataSource3 = Children;

  [rvController release];
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of hard to track what you're saying...and your code needs formatting (above)

Try...

- Kick off your NSURLConnection request in -viewDidLoad
- `[[self tableView] reloadData];` should only be called in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, or after any update to your data array outside of the NSURLConnection request.
- in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` `self.tableDataSource3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:test]; before the [[self tableView] reloadData];`

Comment: @ Jordan Yes the NSURL starts in the viewDidLoad

Comment: @ Jordan  I've got the reloadData only once at the end of the connectionDidFinishLoading. adding the self was a good idea but I'm having the same result. thx

Comment: I have a feeling that the entire didselectRowatIndexPath is incorrect for a reloadData call. I posted a new question.